# Flask : using url_for outside of request context with multiple domains

Tags: flask

## Context

I am running a Flask app that is serving multiple domains for internationalization purpose.

- `hola.es` is used for Spanish users
- `bonjour.fr` is used for French users

There is just one app running, with one common user database, and depending on the request context (mainly which host the request is targeted to or which preferred language the logged-in user defined), the language used for translation and other minor changes occur.

## Problem

The setup is working fine, except for one specific use case: in a worker (I'm using Flask-RQ2 for that purpose), I'd like to batch send emails to all my users. Those emails should contain (absolute) URLs redirecting to the website.

Being out of any request context, `url_for` can't infer the domain it should use to build absolute (`_external=True`) URLs, and is asking to set up the `SERVER_NAME` config variable.

Given the setup I'm using, I can't define the `SERVER_NAME` once and for all in my config since my workers are supposed to handle multiple domain names.

I'd like to be able, while iterating over my users list, to dynamical build absolute urls taking into account for each of them their language preference and hence pointing to the right domain.

## My question

Is there a way, outside of a request context, to **dynamically** define the domain/host/server_name to be used by `url_for` ?

I was surprised to see the `url_for` method does not have a `_host` or similar parameter that could be used to that extent and, if provided, take precedence over the request context (if any) host or `SERVER_NAME` config.

Thanks for your help!